# Is there any reward (apart from monetary winnings) for playing dice poker

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've just started playing The Witcher 2, and I've noticed that since the first game the "dice poker" game has been changed from three rounds to one, which pretty much reduces it to pure luck. As such, it isn't much fun.

Is there any reason for persevering with it, apart from potential monetary winnings? Any other reward, or any quest or dialogue options opened up?

Comment: There are some quests that requires you to play it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one quest per major area in the game related to dice poker. They usually require you to beat 4 or 5 opponents to finish the quest. So, there is a bit of XP to be had in addition to the Orens you win.

**EDIT**

In addition, the last opponent you beat in any Poker Face quest line gives you an opportunity to collect a price, usually a diagram for good gear, rather than taking the Orens.